# How to alert a value in a json array?

Tags: javascript, json, alert

I have a json array and I need to alert a value in it.
The object looks like this:

```
Test = [
         {
          "adj" : [
                    {
                      "nodeTo" : "x",
                      "nodeFrom" : y,
                      "data": 
                              {
                                "$type" : "line",
                                "$color" : "#A989BC",
                                "$value" : "number"
                              }
                     }
                   ],

          "id" : "id1",
          "name" : "name1"
         },
         {
          "adj" : [ ..... ]   // I have many element in the Test array
```

What I want is to alert the value existed in the "data" array which exists in the "adj" array.
I tried this:

```
alert(Test[0]["adj"]["data"]["value"]);
```

But it isn't working.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You're trying to access to the ```adj``` key using ```adjacencies```. Just replace it.

Comment: I wrote this by mistake. I have just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adj is an array:

```
alert(Test[0]["adj"][0]["data"]["value"]);
```

Comment: It worked but I still have one two more questions: 1. If it alerts `"undefined"`, what is that supposed to mean? 2. The value of the "value" is a string, should I have to parse it to string or put `.text()` or something like this?

Comment: A string is the only variable type you can output in an alert. You don't need to parse it. And undefined means that the property (value)  does not exist.

Comment: Actually I should have write `"$value"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
alert(Test[0]["adj"][0]["data"]["value"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(Test[0]["adj"][0]["data"]["value"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an object after `adj`, so you need to add a `[0]`

```
alert(Test[0]["adj"][0]["data"]["value"]);
```

Comment: It worked but I still have one two more questions: 1. If it alerts "undefined", what is that supposed to mean? 2. The value of the "value" is a string, should I have to parse it to string or put .text() or something like this?